# python csv not parsing delimiter

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I am trying to do a simple csv parsing using python, I have the following code:

```
print csvdata
print "\n"
csvparsed = csv.reader(csvdata)

for row in csvparsed:
    print row
```

However, it seems that each row of the parsed data is a single character and not separated by the commas.  Am I missing something here?  This is the output I'm getting:

```
Restaurant ID,2,,
,,,
Menu Name,Breakfast Menu,,

['R']
['e']
['s']
['t']
['a']
['u']
['r']
['a']
['n']
['t']
[' ']
['I']
['D']
['', '']
['2']
['', '']
['', '']
[]
['', '']
['', '']
['', '']
[]
['M']
['e']
['n']
['u']
[' ']
['N']
['a']
['m']
['e']
['', '']
['B']
['r']
['e']
['a']
['k']
['f']
['a']
['s']
['t']
[' ']
['M']
['e']
['n']
['u']
['', '']
['', '']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csv.reader` is meant to be given an iterator over lines of text, which is how an open file works.  You gave it a string, which produces characters when you iterate it.  If you are getting the data from a file, simply give the open file to `csv.reader`, don't read the text first.

If you really do already have the text in a string, then use this:

```
csv.reader(csvdata.splitlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be closer to what you're trying to do:

```
csvparsed = csv.reader(open('csvdata', 'r'))

for row in csvparsed:
    print row
```

With this, and your sample data in a file, I get this output:

```
['Restaurant ID', '2', '', '']
['', '', '', '']
['Menu Name', 'Breakfast Menu', '', '']
```

Comment: my problem was that the data is already in the form of a string and not in a file